# simulate probability with gamma distribution in SAS versus R

Tags: r, sas, probability, gamma

I have some `SAS` code I am trying to translate into `R`.  At one point the `SAS` code simulated a probability `bhrsim` essentially with the following.  I am unsure how to translate this into `R` but show my attempt below.  I do not think I have ever tried to simulate probabilities in this fashion before.  First the `SAS` code:

```
data aa;

seed1    = 11111111 ;
seed2    = 33333333 ;
bhralpha = 2 ;
bhrbeta  = 2 ;

%let rep=50;

do i=1 to &rep;

call rangam(seed1,bhralpha,xgam1);
call rangam(seed2,bhrbeta,xgam2);

bhrsim=xgam1/(xgam1+xgam2);

output;
end;

proc print;
    var seed1 seed2 bhralpha bhrbeta xgam1 xgam2 bhrsim ;
run;
```

I am a little surprised the `call rangam` function does not use both the `alpha` and the `beta` parmeters at the same time.

Here is the output from the above `SAS` code formatted in `R`:

```
SAS.bhrsim <- c(0.43771, 0.28190, 0.47057, 0.30099, 0.25343,
                0.67331, 0.66465, 0.85924, 0.80344, 0.07354,
                0.16228, 0.92554, 0.52711, 0.56944, 0.10370,
                0.05858, 0.89869, 0.88515, 0.74498, 0.17853,
                0.71263, 0.49174, 0.21546, 0.42798, 0.26264,
                0.52674, 0.41922, 0.71119, 0.92044, 0.69456,
                0.33825, 0.55214, 0.42025, 0.93093, 0.20075,
                0.50655, 0.53586, 0.41479, 0.91006, 0.61604,
                0.71669, 0.72271, 0.91053, 0.73377, 0.50403,
                0.28722, 0.54455, 0.26749, 0.58494, 0.17943)

mean(SAS.bhrsim)
#[1] 0.5226472
```

Here is my attempt to translate this into `R`.  I am hoping someone can check that my `R` code is correct and point out any mistakes.  In particular I was not expecting to have to use this line: `bhrsim <- xgam1 / (xgam1 + xgam2)` in `R`, but that just may be because I have never done this before.

```
set.seed(1234)

rep <- 50

bhralpha <- 2
bhrbeta  <- 2

xgam1 <- rgamma(rep, shape = bhralpha, scale = bhrbeta)
xgam2 <- rgamma(rep, shape = bhralpha, scale = bhrbeta)

bhrsim <- xgam1 / (xgam1 + xgam2)

mean(xgam1)
#[1] 3.698261

mean(xgam2)
#[1] 4.427575

mean(bhrsim)
#[1] 0.4477643

R.bhrsim <- c(0.34655843, 0.71945276, 0.20861699, 0.30611308, 0.55605485,
              0.55064680, 0.69470936, 0.45576462, 0.30185399, 0.10438540,
              0.48265790, 0.75655704, 0.42791822, 0.26072882, 0.45523966,
              0.45975115, 0.21874035, 0.22447877, 0.34634855, 0.38155777,
              0.11296304, 0.48800715, 0.37407339, 0.50943619, 0.71306467,
              0.85602900, 0.88723711, 0.05755638, 0.63186913, 0.13553985,
              0.67087093, 0.26015097, 0.26414524, 0.14128396, 0.71854283,
              0.77900243, 0.53769594, 0.46026569, 0.09196446, 0.67574945,
              0.24611917, 0.54923784, 0.60613130, 0.67733881, 0.22317935,
              0.64392641, 0.43528504, 0.44700128, 0.55522003, 0.38119564)
```

Comment: Can you explain the SAS code a little more? The documentation for rangam](http://documentation.sas.com/doc/da/vdmmlcdc/8.1/ds2ref/n0u1p75ctgo024n1jsj22u4g6pf9.htm) says that it takes only two parameters, `seed` and `a`  (== the shape parameter; apparently if you want scale (or rate) not equal to 1 you need to scale the deviate yourself. I'm not sure how `call()` works (docs [here](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/lefunctionsref/p1u7ioka3nk1azn1acbxzqz4n3ii.htm), but ¿maybe? `call rangam(seed, a, varname)` calls `rangam(seed, a)` and assigns the result to `varname` ?

Comment: OK, [this doc](https://www.sfu.ca/sasdoc/sashtml/lgref/z0127832.htm) (I have no idea what versions I'm looking at, just poking around until I find something) confirms my guesses.

Comment: From what I read somewhere the `call` portion of the statement is used to allow the seeds to change for each of the 50 replicates.  I had never seen this before until yesterday.

Comment: But I cannot relocate that SAS documentation link.

Answer (score 2):

According to [SAS documentation for call rangam()](https://www.sfu.ca/sasdoc/sashtml/lgref/z0127832.htm), `call rangam(seed, a, x)` generates a Gamma random deviate with *shape* equal to `a`, using random seed `seed`, and assigns the result to `x` (and updates the seed *internally* — calling `call rangam(...)` a second time with the same `seed` argument uses **a new value from the RNG stream** (the idiom seems very strange to me but what do I know?).  So the R equivalent is `set.seed(seed)` (once, at the beginning of the loop); `x <- rgamma(1, a)` (R allows you to set the rate or scale != 1 by specifying additional arguments; the first argument is the number of deviates requested.)

So I believe the R equivalent would be

```r
set.seed(111111)
xgam1 <- rgamma(50, shape = 2)
xgam2 <- rgamma(50, shape = 2)
bhrsim <- xgam1 / (xgam1 + xgam2)
mean(bhrsim)
## [1] 0.5579772
```

For what it's worth, this is a standard algorithm for generating Beta(alpha, beta) - distributed random numbers (although not, apparently, *identical* to whatever R uses internally ...)

```r
set.seed(111111)
bhrsim <- rbeta(50, shape1 = 2, shape2 = 2)
mean(bhrsim)
## [1] 0.5324306
```

Comment: I am a little confused because the `SAS` code defines `bhrbeta = beta parameter for beta distribution` and `bhralpha = alpha parameter for beta distribution`.  Elsewhere `α` is known as the `shape` parameter and `β` is called the `scale` parameter.  But in the `SAS` code both `bhralpha` and `bhrbeta` are treated as `shape` parameters in these lines: `call rangam(seed1,bhralpha,xgam1); call rangam(seed2,bhrbeta,xgam2);`  In other words, `bhrbeta` seemingly is defined as a  `scale` parameter at the top of the `SAS` code but seemingly is treated as a `shape` parameter in the `SAS` code itself.

Comment: I agree with @MarkMiller. The SAS code looks suspicious to me. I fear it may not be doing what it is intended to do. If you can, I would consult the original developers and check any documentation you may have to compare what it should be doing with what it actually is doing. I realise that this may not be possible.

Comment: @MarkMiller just to add a link, here is how Beta(a, b) is generated, you could compare it with your SAS source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Random_variate_generation